# WHERE clause with the same field name

Tags: sql, where-clause

I can't find this online, but I want to update my database where Id= 1 and id= 37

I thought of doing the BETWEEN but I don't wanna update all the IDs between it, I just want those two. Can someone tell me the syntax for that?

Comment: Do you want to update the records with those IDs? Or do you just want to select them?

Comment: I want to Update them both with whatever other things I am setting to them

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve based on "I want to Update them both with whatever other things I am setting to them"

Comment: @TommyO Mike's answer was a good solution to my question. I wanted to update two different records based upon the same field which in this case was their ID number

Comment: That's good it resolved your issue, but what Mike showed you to do did not **update** anything, just merely selected it from a table. If that is the answer to your question, you should consider rephrasing the question to something like "how do I select two different records based on a single field". The term **update** means something very particular regarding database.

Comment: I Did use it as an Update script, my question was for updating, but the IN operator did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `in` operator

```
Update Users
SET Sleep=1
Where ID IN (1, 37);
```

Comment: This worked. Now if I this was my full script
UPDATE Users SET Age='$NewAge' WHERE Id IN ('$Id',"$otherID") is there a way to set 2 ages? Like $newage1 and $newage2? Would that be another IN clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN clause, it goes something like:

... `where ID in (1,2,3,...)` ...